# clean input values inside hide <div>

Tags: javascript

I used javascript to hide `div` depend on `radio button` value for example I unhide `div` `#one` and fill up input fields and realize I'm in the wrong transaction and click the radio button to change the desire transaction but without clean up all input fields.

is there any way to clean up input values(I mean by clean up is to empty input fields)if user select on the radio button.

**script**

```
<script>
function showhidediv( rad )
    {
        var rads = document.getElementsByName( rad.name );
        document.getElementById( 'one' ).style.display = ( rads[0].checked ) ? 'block' : 'none';
        document.getElementById( 'two' ).style.display = ( rads[1].checked ) ? 'block' : 'none';
        document.getElementById( 'three' ).style.display = ( rads[2].checked ) ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
</script>
```

**form**

```
<form action="aef.php" method="post">
  <label>Date</label><br />
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" name="date" /><br /><br />

  <input type="radio" name="transtype" value="0" onclick="showhidediv(this);" checked /> LBC Payment
  <input type="radio" name="transtype" value="1" onclick="showhidediv(this);" /> Additional Funds
  <input type="radio" name="transtype" value="2" onclick="showhidediv(this);" /> miscellaneous expense

  <br /><br />
  <div id="one">

   <label>LBC Tracking No.</label><br />
   <input type="text" value="" name="lbc" /><br /><br />

   <label>Transaction Code</label><br />
   <input type="text" value="" name="code" id="code" /><br /><br />

   <label>Credit Amout</label><br />
   <input type="text" name="credit_amout" /> 

  </div>

  <div id="two" class="divhide">
    <label>Debit Amout</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="debit_amout" />
  </div>

  <div id="three" class="divhide">
    <label>Expenses Description</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="expenses" value="" name="description" /><br /><br />

    <label>miscellaneous expense</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="credit_amout" />
  </div>


  <br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Add Expenses" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Use `document.getElementById('one').getElementsBYTagName('input')` to find all the inputs in that DIV, loop over them, and set their values to empty strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this could give you idea how

on the javascript

```
<script>
function showhidediv( rad )
    {
        var rads = document.getElementsByName( rad.name );
        document.getElementById( 'one' ).style.display = ( rads[0].checked ) ? 'block' : 'none';
        document.getElementById( 'two' ).style.display = ( rads[1].checked ) ? 'block' : 'none';
        document.getElementById( 'three' ).style.display = ( rads[2].checked ) ? 'block' : 'none';
        var input = new Array();
        if (rads[0].checked) {
          input = document.querySelectorAll('#one input');
        }

        if (rads[1].checked) {
          input = document.querySelectorAll('#two input');
        }

        if (rads[2].checked) {
          input = document.querySelectorAll('#three input');
        }

        clear_inputs(input);
    }
function clear_inputs(input) {
  for (var i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      input[i].value = '';
    };
}
</script>
```

you can start modifying the code according to what you need

the function clear_inputs will clear the value of the input

you can improve this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *fieldset* element to surround the inputs. Give it a name, then you can simply clear all the elements inside it, e.g. using a cut–down version of the form:

```
<form ...>

  <input type="radio" name="transtype" value="0" onclick="showhidediv(this);" checked> LBC Payment
  <input type="radio" name="transtype" value="1" onclick="showhidediv(this);"> Additional Funds
  <input type="radio" name="transtype" value="2" onclick="showhidediv(this);"> miscellaneous expense

  <div id="one">
  <fieldset name="f0">

   <label>LBC Tracking No.</label><br>
   <input type="text" value="" name="lbc"><br><br>

   <label>Transaction Code</label><br>
   <input type="text" value="" name="code" id="code"><br><br>

   <label>Credit Amout</label><br>
   <input type="text" name="credit_amout">
  </fieldset>
 </div>
</form>
```

Then in the function:

```
function showhidediv(element) {

  // Get the field set
  var set = element.form.f0.elements;

  // Reset the elements to their default value
  for (var i=0, iLen=set.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    set[i].value = set[i].defaultValue;
  }

  // Do other stuff...
}
```

If you don't like the default effect of the fieldset on the form layout, you can remove the border and change its *style.display* property.

Also, when doing:

```
document.getElementById( 'one' ).style.display = rads[0].checked? 'block' : 'none';
```

you should toggle the value between 'none' and '' (empty string) so that the element adopts its default or inherited style, whatever that might be.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this function to clear data from inputs, but it can also help you to read an element contained in the parent div, read the values and decide what to do..

```
     function clear_inputs(div){
     parent_content=document.getElementById(div); 
     child_elements=parent_content.getElementsByTagName('input');
     co = child_elements.length;co--;
    /*elements goes from 0 to ∞, length goes from 1 to ∞, thats why c-- to loop thru the elements.*/

    /*console.log(elementos);console.log(co); use this if you want to see the elements you are working with on browser's console*/

    for (i=0;i<=co;i++) {child_elements[i].value = "";}// empty values for inputs 
                         }
      }
```